# Cannot cast String to my list object

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter

At this line: `ListItemsModel listItem = getItem(position);` in my adapter class, I get the casting error.

Very strange error, considering I am not at all casting a `String` to my `ListItemsModel` object. In fact this code was working just fine, and then I updated my launcher icons (unrelated) and now I get this error. Any ideas? Thanks.

**MainListActivity**

```
package org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<ListItemsModel> itemsList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListViewItemAdapter itemsAdapter;
    private ListView itemsView;
    EditText newItemET;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_list);

        newItemET = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        // read items that were persisted in list, before adapter is created with the list
        readItems();
        itemsAdapter = new ListViewItemAdapter(MainListActivity.this, itemsList);
        itemsView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);

        itemsView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);

        setUpListDetailsClickListener();
        setupDeleteItemClickListener();
    }

    // Enables a listener, to go to list details activity
    public void setUpListDetailsClickListener(){
        itemsView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                    long id) {

                if (itemsView.getItemAtPosition(position) != null) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainListActivity.this, ListItemActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("item name", itemsView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainListActivity.this, "Add item to list.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Adds item to list
    public void addItem(View v) {
        if (!newItemET.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            ListItemsModel item = new ListItemsModel(newItemET.getText().toString(), 1);
            itemsAdapter.add(item);
            newItemET.setText("");
            writeItems();

        }
            // soft keyboard down
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(newItemET.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    // Enables listener to delete item
    private void setupDeleteItemClickListener() {
        itemsView.setOnItemLongClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapter,
                                                   View item, int pos, long id) {
                        // Remove the item within array at position
                        itemsList.remove(pos);
                        // Refresh the adapter
                        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        writeItems();
                        // Return true consumes the long click event (marks it handled)
                        return true;
                    }

                });
    }

    // Reads list from file (saved)
    private void readItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File groceryFile = new File(filesDir, "grocery.txt");
        try {
            itemsList = new ArrayList<ListItemsModel>(FileUtils.readLines(groceryFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Writes new items to list (saves it), or refreshes after delete item
    private void writeItems() {
        File filesDir = getFilesDir();
        File groceryFile = new File(filesDir, "grocery.txt");
        try {
            FileUtils.writeLines(groceryFile, itemsList);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**ListViewItemAdapter**

```
package org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 5/11/16.
 */
public class ListViewItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItemsModel> {


    public ListViewItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItemsModel> items){
        super(context, 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;


        ListItemsModel listItem = getItem(position);

        if(row == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.itemTitleET = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
            holder.itemQtyET = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.itemQty);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.itemTitleET.setText(listItem.getTitle());
        // setText() only accepts Strings
        holder.itemQtyET.setText(String.valueOf(listItem.getQty()));

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        EditText itemTitleET;
        EditText itemQtyET;
    }
}
```

**ListItemsModel**

```
package org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist;

/**
 * Created by mizu on 5/11/16.
 */
public class ListItemsModel {


    private String title;
    private int qty = 0;

    public ListItemsModel(String t, int q){
        this.title = t;
        this.qty = q;
    }

    public ListItemsModel(String t){
        this.title = t;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getQty(){
        return qty;
    }

    public void setQty(int qty){
        this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

**LogCat**

```
05-12 00:03:30.972 28958-28958/org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist, PID: 28958
                                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist.ListItemsModel
                                                                                   at org.azurespot.nonigrocerylist.ListViewItemAdapter.getView(ListViewItemAdapter.java:29)
                                                                                   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2842)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1290)
                                                                                   at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1202)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                                   at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:391)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1835)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:725)
                                                                                   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:616)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5802)
                                                                                   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2881)
                                                                                   at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18425)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2241)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1537)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
                                                                                   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6563)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
                                                                                   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: At which line u r getting exception?

Comment: I mention it at the top... it's in the adapter class, when I try to get item at position: `ListItemsModel listItem = getItem(position);`

Comment: You should change it by _ListItemsModel listItem = (ListItemsModel)getItem(position);_. Because _getItem()_ method returns the object and you didn't specify it.

Comment: I tried this, but my compiler says it is redundant, and I still get the error.

Comment: Then override getItem() method in adapter class and change it to with your model class.

Comment: @PiyushGupta array adapter doesn't return you the generic object. It is the code from ArrayAdapter class 
`public T getItem(int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }`

Comment: I see, so I should create my own `getItem` method so it returns a `ListItemsModel` object? But why does it think it is a `String`? Very odd.

Comment: Add this method in your adapter class **@Override
    public ListItemsModel getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }**

Comment: @NoniA., Are you still working on this? Long time no hear from me.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
public class ListViewItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItemsModel> {

 ArrayList<ListItemsModel> items;
    public ListViewItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItemsModel> items){
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.items=items;
    }

    @Override
    public ListItemsModel getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;


        ListItemsModel listItem = getItem(position);

        if(row == null) {
            row = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.checkBox = (CheckBox)row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            holder.itemTitleET = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.listItem);
            holder.itemQtyET = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.itemQty);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        holder.itemTitleET.setText(listItem.getTitle());
        // setText() only accepts Strings
        holder.itemQtyET.setText(String.valueOf(listItem.getQty()));

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        CheckBox checkBox;
        EditText itemTitleET;
        EditText itemQtyET;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but it now says there is a null pointer on the array list `items`. Is there another way? I have to create the actual list in my main activity.

Comment: Check the constructor @NoniA.

Comment: Sorry, which constructor?

Comment: This one _ArrayList<ListItemsModel> items;
    public ListViewItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListItemsModel> items){
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.items=items;
    }_

Comment: I don't understand what I am supposed to check to get rid of the null pointer, can you elaborate?

Comment: I understand the null pointer is because the `ArrayList` has  not been created yet, but as I said, it should be created in my main activity, not in the adapter class, so I was puzzled how to use your code.

Comment: Oh you added a line there! Sorry ;)

Comment: Ugh... I added it, but it still gets the same error. Now at this line: `return items.get(position);`. :(

Comment: For some reason it thinks that what is at the position is a String, but it is not. It's a `ListItemsModel` object within the array list.

Answer (score 0):

Try my CustomListView Sample without @Override the getItem().

> MainActivity.java

```
package listview.customlistview;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

String m_txt[] = {"one" , "two" , "three" , "four", "five"};
int m_img [] = {R.drawable.ic_launcher ,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher ,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher ,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher ,
        R.drawable.ic_launcher};

ListView m_list;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    m_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_items);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < m_txt.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(m_img[i],m_txt[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.listitem, rowItems);
    m_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_list.setOnItemClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Item " + (position) + ": " + rowItems.get(position).getTxt(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

}
}
```

> CustomListViewAdapter

```
package listview.customlistview;

import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RowItem> {

Context context;

public CustomListViewAdapter(Context context, int resourceId,
                             List<RowItem> items) {
    super(context, resourceId, items);
    this.context = context;
}

/*private view holder class*/
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView m_pic;
    TextView m_title;
    Button m_btn;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)    {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    RowItem rowItem = getItem(position);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.m_title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.m_textview);
        holder.m_btn = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.m_buttonview);
        holder.m_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.m_imageview);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.m_title.setText(rowItem.getTxt());

    holder.m_pic.setImageResource(rowItem.getImage());

   holder.m_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

           Toast.makeText(context, position + " clicked" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   });

    return convertView;
}
}
```

> RowItem

```
package listview.customlistview;


public class RowItem {

private int image;
private String txt;

public RowItem(int imageview , String textview)
{
    this.image = imageview;
    this.txt = textview;
}


public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getTxt() {
    return txt;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public void setTxt(String txt) {
    this.txt = txt;
}
}
```

Check my *Adapter class Constructor*.

This may helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but what is your `resourceId`? What should go there? I am using 0, but it seemed to work before. Plus my error is talking about a casting... which is strange, since I don't cast a `String`, the item at the position is an object type with 3 components. String is one type, but not all.

Comment: see my MainActivity . resourceId refers your list_items layout

Comment: I see... I tried to add my row layout to the constructor, but it doesn't help. Still get the casting error.

Comment: But if I can't translate what it means in terms of my own code, which I'm having a hard time doing, then it's not helping, unfortunately. That's why it's better if things are pointed out in my own code. If you think of anything in my code, let me know. Thanks.